# What is the good manner to place foreign keys between tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, foreign-keys, standards

I was looking at advantureworks DB, and I have asked myself "Why table A have a FK to table B, if the B table could have a FK to table A"

In more complex way, pls tell me if there is an important difference between:

```
CONSTRAINT FK_A_B   FOREIGN KEY(A_Key)
        REFERENCES B(B_Key),
```

and

```
CONSTRAINT FK_B_A   FOREIGN KEY(B_Key)
        REFERENCES B(A_Key),
```

Comment: Well, to explain myself for this question (I know that this one is basic): it's hard to find answer for it, I don't really know how to ask uncle google

Comment: Well it depends on your data model. Would you care to post a real-life example of yours? e.g. to model Author-Book relationship (where book only can have one author) you would have `FK_Book_Author FOREIGN KEY (author_id) REFERENCES Author(author_id)`

Comment: A FK must by unique.  Really you have two tables with same column unique?  Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a rule written in stone for choosing your keys (there are rules though) it's more a question of a common sense.

If you have tables e.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE [Person](

    [PersonID] [int] PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    [MiddleName] varchar (20) NULL,
    [LastName] varchar(20) NOT NULL,

)
```

And:

```
CREATE TABLE [PersonInfo](

    [PersonID] [int] FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [dbo].[Person] (PersonID) NOT NULL,
    [Phone] varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    [Email] varchar (20) NULL,
    [Address] varchar(20) NOT NULL,
)
```

A foreign key in the PersonInfo table enforces the rule that a value PesonID cannot be inserted into the PesonInfo table before it exists in the Person table where a Person is uniquely defined by a primary key (PersonID)

This is a very simple example, relationships will become more complicated on a real database, but the point is that there is a logical relationship between two tables.

You can choose (if it makes sense) your foreign and primary keys, but there is a lot of other things you need to think about when designing a database vs. just a simple answer

You can read more:

[Primary and Foreign Key Constraints](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179610.aspx)

[Creating Foreign Key Relationships](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189049.aspx)

I hope this helps